# Match comments without comment character

Tags: .net, regex

I have this C# regex 
`(/\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*/)|(//.*)` that matches `/* */` and `//` style comments.

[image]

I would like to exclude `//`, `/*` and `*/` from my matches. How can i do so?

Comment: Could you give an example of the desired outcome? What have you tried?

Comment: right right, specified

Comment: Thanks for editing, I also added the appropriate tag. The answer you got links to a PCRE demo, but this may be the same in .NET syntax vs PCRE syntax.

Comment: It's the same for this example, so I guess it's alright :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lookarounds:

```
((?<=\/\*)(.|[\r\n])*?(?=\*\/))|((?<=\/\/).*)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Sc9eqU/1